# Можно ли подключить SSL только для одной страницы сайта?

Tags: https, ssl

Можно ли подключить SSL сертификат только для одной страницы сайта?

К примеру: https://site.ru/korzina/, а остальной сайт http://site.ru/.

Просто сейчас, мне с одной стороны рекламщики говорят, что так можно сделать, инженеры которые обслуживают сервер говорят, что только для всего сайта можно подключить SSL отдельно для страницы сайта нельзя.

Comment: Пусть включают для всего сайта, главное, что бы не отключили возможность работать без ssl.

А дальше все разруливается кодом - просто вставляются правильные ссылки. Можно конечно поправить конфиг сервера, что бы он делал редирект.

Но есть  решение проще - делайте весь сайт на ssl, Да, нагрузка будет чуть больше, зато в рейтинге поисковиков подымиться.

Comment: Технически-то можно (шаманством в конфиге apache2/nginx), вот только меня в первую очередь интересует - а зачем? Если есть возможность включить https для сайта целиком, то этим следует обязательно воспользоваться, в 2016 году-то.

Comment: Я с вами согласен, но проблема в том, что есть старый сайт с позициями в поисковых системах. Но для рекламы в Google merchant нужно, чтобы сайт поддерживал https. Но при переходе на https есть риск потери позиции, ТИЦа и прочего в Яндексе. Яркий пример это сайт lenta.ru который после перехода на https потерял ТИЦ и сейчас он равен 0.

Comment: А вот тут про ленту.ру и тиц реквестирую более подробную информацию, а то сейчас это звучит очень-очень глупо и неправдоподобно

Answer (score 2):

правы и «рекламщики» и «инженеры». но каждый по-своему.

да, можно сделать, чтобы сайт работал и по протоколу *http* и по протоколу *https*. но, естественно, **весь** сайт.

а в дополнение можно, к примеру, все обращения по протоколу *https* (кроме обращения по *url* `/korzina`) перенаправлять на такой же *url*, но с протоколом *http*.

---

если же у вас есть опасения по поводу каких-то там сайтовых рейтингов, вы можете «корзину» сделать на другом сайте. имя которого может быть поддоменом в домене, используемом вашим сайтом (`blabla.site.ru`) или вообще другим доменным именем (`blabla.ru`).

Answer (score 2):

Ну... **вообще-то можно**.

Технически, **на одном домене** по HTTP и HTTPS можно разместить **два разных сайта**. У них *"совершенно случайно"* могут совпадать корневые страницы.

- *Same Origin Policy* считает разные протоколы достаточным отличием для запрета доступа к ресурсам без явного разрешения.
- Если сайты совершенно разные, это скорее собьёт с толку и затруднит применение вещей, предполагающих "повышение" ссылок до HTTPS (скажем, HSTS).

Эти протоколы по умолчанию используют разные порты, 80 и 443 соответственно. Из-за особенностей DNS оба протокола должны обслуживаться одними и теми же машинами, но в пределах машины порты 80 и 443 могут слушать два разных процесса, настроенные по-разному. Это в теории. На практике я такого не встречал.

На практике: в конфигурационном файле [nginx](https://nginx.org/ru/) можно сделать один блок с `listen 80`, указав там, что обслуживать по HTTP, а в блоке с `listen 443 ssl` указать настройки для HTTPS.

---

#### Но зачем?